# Environment aligned doesn't output first part in bracket

Tags: equations, align, brackets

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        [c\mathbf{v}+c'\mathbf{v}',\mathbf{w}]=&c[\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}]+c'[\mathbf{v}',\mathbf{w}],\\
        [\mathbf{v},c\mathbf{w}+c'\mathbf{w}']=&c[\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}]+c'[\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}'],
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

In this code, `[c\mathbf{v}+c'\mathbf{v}',\mathbf{w}]` is not shown in the equation. Is it because of the `aligned` environment? How to fix it?

Comment: As a comment, I found both `\begin{aligned}{}` and `\begin{aligned}\\` work. Thanks all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update Jan. 2021**. The current version of the `amsmath` package, `2020/09/23 v2.17i`, no longer generates the problem described in the OP's query. Hence, taking "precautions" such as inserting a `\relax` or `{}` element before a `[` element at the start of a line is no longer necessary.

What you're experiencing is the fact that the `aligned` environment -- as set up by the `amsmath` package -- is set to scan ahead for a positioning argument such as `[t]` or `[b]`. Material that's found in square brackets but which doesn't meet this format is simply discarded.

I can think of two solutions:

- Insert `\relax` before the left square bracket (it will stop the bracket from being interpreted as an argument);
- Insert `{}` (an empty math atom) before the left square bracket;
- Load the `mathtools` package instead of the `amsmath` package, as the former takes care to disable this generally-unexpected-and-unwelcome setting.

A separate matter: To get the correct (and symmetric) amount of spacing around the `=` symbols, you should write `&=` rather than `=&`.

Comment: Or use `\lbrack` instead of `[` when at the start of a line.