# Strange behavior when using brackets in aligned environment

Tags: align

At ran into what at this point seems like a bug to me. When using brackets around a term before the first equality in an `aligned` environment, the enclosed quantity simply disappears from the output. For example, the following MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        [a] = [b]
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

When reomving the first bracket, i.e. the one in front of `a`, everything looks as expected.

[image]

However, when reinserting the first bracket and instead removing the second one as well as those around `b`, i.e. with `[a = b` compilation is aborted and I get a nasty error stating

```
File ended while scanning use of \\aligned@a.
```

Has anyone encountered this problem before and knows of a fix?

Comment: We've had this before, in some form or another - the `aligned` environment takes an optional argument, which is how your input is interpreted. You need to insert something that avoid this confusion: `\relax[a]` or `{}[a]`...

Comment: potential duplicate: [`aligned` environment doesn't output first part in the bracket](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281939/579)

Comment: Alternatively you can load the `mathtools` package, which with its default settings solves this problem.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's indeed a duplicate. Weird that it didn't show up in my original search.

Comment: @Casimir -- well, i knew where to look: it's there under "often referenced questions" on the meta list.