# Why can't I start two lines in a row with a bracket ("[") in the tabular environment?

Tags: tables, compilation-error

I've been using LaTeX for 7 years and I can't figure this one out.

This compiles:

```
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c| }
 \hline
 [TCTA]10 & 2637 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

This also compiles (I can put any character there on the first slot of the second table line, including a space character like \;, and it will still work):

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c| }
 \hline
 [TCTA]10 & 2637 \\
 A [TCTA]8 TCTG [TCTA]1 & 2093 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

But this does **not** compile:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c| }
 \hline
 [TCTA]10 & 2637 \\
 [TCTA]8 TCTG [TCTA]1 & 2093 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

The error I get is something I can't make sense of, and Google hasn't helped:

"Missing number, treated as zero." It says a number should have been at the end of the second line. "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).... Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, ..., bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!"

The only other answer I could find that relates to this had to do with a \textwidth command, which I'm not using.

A list of packages I have included:

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts,bm,centernot,graphicx,mathrsfs,mathtools,physics,setspace,subcaption,titlesec,wrapfig}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! That's because latex thinks it is an optional spacing argument for \\. Use `\\ {[TCTA]}`.

Comment: The group is not necessary (though not harmful here). I would use ``\\\relax [TCTA...`` or ``\\\lbrack TCTA...``.

Comment: potential duplicate: [`aligned` environment doesn't output first part in the bracket](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281939)  Although it 
 cites `align`, the parsing of a bracket after a double backslash is the same in a `tabular` environment.

Comment: Yes, this is probably relevant. [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34466/error-with-square-bracket-in-table) (“Error with square bracket in table”) is about `tabular`, specifically.

Comment: I can't upvote comments but thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you so much, Bernard and frougon!

This works:

```
[TCTA]10 & 2637 \\
{[TCTA]}8 TCTG [TCTA]1 & 2093 \\
```

This also works:

```
[TCTA]10 & 2637 \\\relax
[TCTA]8 TCTG [TCTA]1 & 2093 \\ %\relax on last line will throw error
```

And this works, too:

```
[TCTA]10 & 2637 \\
\lbrack TCTA]8 TCTG [TCTA]1 & 2093 \\
```

Comment: To explain a bit what is happening, `\\ ` takes an optional argument: `\\[some length]` will adjust the vertical spacing by that amount.  When TeX sees `\\ ` followed by (ignoring whitespace) `[`, it thinks you're doing the optional argument.  The ways that work are ways to tell TeX that you're not using the optional argument (another possibility is `\\{}`).

Comment: I can't upvote comments yet but thank you so much for the explanation!