# Problem with aligned environment in latex?

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, align, amsmath

Why does `[X]` does not display? `X` would appear if I removed the brackets. Is that a bug?

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
 [X] &= 1\\
 [Y] &= 2,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Related, potential duplicate: [`aligned` environment doesn't output first part in the bracket](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281939)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another solution is to load the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools) package. The `mathtools` package is a (very significant!) superset of the `amsmath` package which also fixes a couple of *de facto* bugs -- such as mis-interpreting `[X]` as the optional argument of `\begin{aligned}` -- of the `amsmath` package. For more about this bug, see section 2.1 of the user guide of the `mathtools` package.

To wit,

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
   [X] &= 1\\
   [Y] &= 2,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

works exactly as expected:

[image]

A nice aspect of this solution is that you needn't remember to insert `{}` after `\begin{aligned}` if the next line begins with an object -- such as `[X]` -- that's encased in square brackets.

Answer (score 8):

`aligned` takes an optional argument and so it is mistakening `[X]` for that option.  The way to overcome is to place something innocuous after the `{aligned}`, but before the `[X]`.  Here I place an empty group `{}`.

Note that the option, when employed, is a vertical-alignment positioning specification, such as `[t]` or `[b]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}{}
 [X] &= 1\\
 [Y] &= 2,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```