# What is the difference between \\* and \\ *?

Tags: math-mode, matrices, mathtools, syntax, semantics

I used a `*` in a `bsmallmatrix` and found a curious effect. If I write `\\*` the `*` is not printed whereas with `\\ *` it is. Do you guys know why this happens?

My tiny example and screenshot follow below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bsmallmatrix}a&a\\*&*\end{bsmallmatrix}
\]

\[
\begin{bsmallmatrix}a&a\\ *&*\end{bsmallmatrix}
\]

 \end{document}
```

[image: StarExample]

Answer (score 14):

AMS matrices use a modified form of lookahead that does not skip white space looking for `*` and `[` this is so that you can have

```
\begin{matrix}
a & b \\
[x] & y
\end{matrix}
```

with the `[` taken as text to be printed not (as it would in a standard `array` environment} be equivalent to  `\\[x]`  and give an error that `x` isn't a valid length.

`*` is similar to `[` as the array `\\`  command has a `*` form `\\*` even though it is equivalent to `\\`  as there is no page breaking. (`\\*` generally is a line break that does not allow a page break at that point).

Comment: @campa nothing (I was just adding a note about that, see added text:-)

Comment: @campa although the code is shared with tabular and the fact that it was there meant that `\\*` almost worked "for free" in longtable.

Comment: I just compiled your example here without the error you describe!

Comment: @jessexknight I think you misunderstood: the answer explicitly explains that AMS guards against this kind of errors. Try it with `\begin{array}{cc}` instead of `\begin{matrix}`  and you'll get the error.

Comment: @jessexknight then you constructed the example incorrectly, `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}$\begin{array}{cc}a & b \\ [x] & y\end{array}$\end{document}` does give an error.

Comment: Thanks @campa yes I misunderstood that `mathrools` / the AMS matrices avoids this problem -- sorry about that!

Comment: What's been ignored in both answers so far is that this "exception" was made after too many questions about error messages from `\\ [xxx]`, and the obvious fact that math expressions are often wrapped in square brackets.

Comment: Just to be clear, the `\\ ` to which you refer is really just double-backslash, not double-backslash-space, and you are just working around MathJax escaping, right?

Comment: @LSpice no mathjax here. The amsmath change is for the case when there is white space (normally a newline not a space, but a space is the same)  between `\\ ` and the `[`

Comment: Sorry, [Markdown](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558610/what-is-the-difference-between-and/558611#comment1408970_558611)—at least I hope that's the right name for whatever's on SE.  (Too much time on MO makes me forget they're not synonymous.)  What I meant is that, when you refer to, for example, "the `\\ ` command", the ` ` there isn't part of the command name, right?  (I know you are *also* referring to the issue of whitespace following that command.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Oh, interesting piece of history. I had no idea.

Comment: Fixed in newer versions [equations - Environment aligned doesn't output first part in bracket - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281939/environment-aligned-doesnt-output-first-part-in-bracket)