# Why doesn't the first term in this equation appear?

Tags: equations, amsmath, overleaf

I have this on latex

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
[A_i, A_j]&=i\varepsilon_{ijk}A_k\\
[B_i, B_j]&=i\varepsilon_{ijk}B_k\\
[A_i, B_j]&=0
\end{aligned}
\label{eq:10}
\end{equation}
```

and the output is:

[image]

Why isn't the `[A_i, A_j]` appearing? How can I fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Without a proper functioning [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) it is difficult to help you out.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you update your TeX distribution and, in particular, the `amsmath` package. On my system (MacTeX2020, w/ all updates installed), your code does not cause `[A_i, A_j]` to disappear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to NBurs answer here is the warning I get in the log

```
Package amsmath Warning: Bracket group [A_i, A_j] at formula start!
(amsmath)                It could be a misspelled positional argument.
(amsmath)                If it belongs to the formula add a \relax in
(amsmath)                front to hide it on input line 11.
```

Basically `aligned` takes an optional argument in `[]`, and in `amsmath`'s default setup spaces are allowed between `\begin{aligned}` and `[...]`.

You can either use `\begin{aligned}\relax` or load `mathtools` (good idea anyway, disclamer I maintain it) as `mathtools` changes `aligned` such that space between `\begin{aligned}` and the argument in `[]`'s are not allowed.

Comment: I wished to add this warning… ;) By the way, even without the optional argument, I've got the correct output. Seems weird?

Comment: @NBur it depends on the version of `amsmath` you use.

Comment: I use the amsmath 2020/09/23 v2.17i. Output is right without the optional argument, but I've got the warning message.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're using an outdated version of the `amsmath` package (which provides the `aligned` environment). With the *current* version of `amsmath` (`amsmath 2020/09/23 v2.17i`), the issue you encountered is no longer present.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' environment
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  [A_i, A_j]&=i\varepsilon_{ijk}A_k\\
  [B_i, B_j]&=i\varepsilon_{ijk}B_k\\
  [A_i, B_j]&=0
\end{aligned}
\label{eq:10}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could maybe update your answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281943/82917 and then we might mark this question as duplicate.

Comment: @campa - Many thanks for locating the earlier posting and for suggesting that I update it suitably. I've updated the answer I gave there and have closed the present query.

Answer (score 1):

From the `amsmath` documentation:

> The aligned environment takes an optional argument that indicates its vertical position in relation to surrounding material: t, c, or b for top, center, or bottom.

In your code this optional argument is read as `[A_i, A_j]`, which is unknown. And you get the warning reported in the other answer by @daleif.

Thus you have to write

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}\text{at top }
    \begin{aligned}[t]
    [A_i, A_j]&=i\varepsilon_{ijk}A_k\\
    [B_i, B_j]&=i\varepsilon_{ijk}B_k\\
    [A_i, B_j]&=0
    \end{aligned}\text{ after eq}
    \label{eq:10t}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}\text{centered }
    \begin{aligned}[c]
    [A_i, A_j]&=i\varepsilon_{ijk}A_k\\
    [B_i, B_j]&=i\varepsilon_{ijk}B_k\\
    [A_i, B_j]&=0
    \end{aligned}\text{ after eq}
    \label{eq:10c}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}\text{at bottom }
    \begin{aligned}[b]
    [A_i, A_j]&=i\varepsilon_{ijk}A_k\\
    [B_i, B_j]&=i\varepsilon_{ijk}B_k\\
    [A_i, B_j]&=0
    \end{aligned}\text{ after eq}
    \label{eq:10b}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: AFAICT, the question is *not* about where to place the equation number. Instead, it's about why the `[A_i, A_j]` term doesn't show up. Changing `\begin{aligned}` to `\begin{aligned}[c]` treats the symptom, not the cause, of the problem.

Comment: Adding `[t],` `[c]` or `[b]` treats the cause, since `[A_i, A_j]` is no more the optional argument and thus is diplayed. But indeed my answer lacked this explanation.

Comment: In my view, the real solution is to fully update one's TeX distribution and, in particular, the `amsmath` package. With `amsmath 2020/09/23 v2.17i`, the problem encountered by the OP doesn't arise at all.

Comment: @Mico Sure! The output is right, but there is still the warning.