# don't understand a particular error message I'm getting

Tags: math-mode, errors, align

When I type

```
$$ A_n\ =\ \left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
[\hskip.017in 0,1\hskip.017in] & {} & n\ {\rm is\ even} \\
[\hskip.017in -1,0\hskip.017in] & {} & n\ {\rm is\ odd} \\
\end{array}\right.\ , $$
```

I get an error message claiming "illegal unit of measure" and "missing number." I can't find anything wrong with the code. What am I missing?

Comment: dupe [equations - Environment aligned doesn't output first part in bracket - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281939/environment-aligned-doesnt-output-first-part-in-bracket) ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the first `[` follows `\\` and is mistaken for introducing the optional argument. Use `\relax` or, better, use the proper tool.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$$ A_n\ =\ \left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
[\hskip.017in 0,1\hskip.017in] & {} & n\ {\rm is\ even} \\ \relax
[\hskip.017in -1,0\hskip.017in] & {} & n\ {\rm is\ odd} \\
\end{array}\right.\ , $$

\[
A_n=\begin{cases}
[0,1]  & \text{$n$ is even,} \\
[-1,0] & \text{$n$ is odd,}
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have little doubts about which rendering is better both for input and output. If you want to align the two intervals to the right, add `\hphantom{-}`:

```
\[
A_n=\begin{cases}
\hphantom{-}[0,1]  & \text{$n$ is even,} \\
[-1,0] & \text{$n$ is odd,}
\end{cases}
\]
```

[image]

I'd avoid the comma hanging from nowhere.

Note that `\rm` has been deprecated for about 30 years and `$$` since LaTeX version 1, about 40 years ago.

Comment: You might want to use `\textup`, just in case this is used within an italic environment like a theorem.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'm not sure why the text should be different from the context.

Comment: Okay, but it's nice to know that `\text`, all by itselt, follows the style of the surrounding environment.

Comment: Another option would be `[\hphantom{-}0,1]`, so that the left brackets align.  I don't know if that would be better.

Answer (score 2):

the `[`is being seen as an optional argument, which takes a length, `\\[5pt]` so use

```
....\\ \relax
[....]
```

to hide  the `[` from `\\`

Note `$$` and`\hskip` are TeX primitives that should not be used in LaTeX, use `\[` and `\hspace` (but avoid `\hspace`in math)  `\rm` has not been defined by default in latex since 1993, use `\textrm{ is  odd}`